# Heroku app crashes on boot timeout (60 seconds) but app started in 30 seconds

Tags: java, spring, heroku, timeout

My heroku web app (java/ spring framework /boot) shows start up times of 20 - 30 seconds but still shows a port binding timeout of over 60 seconds in the logs.
What is causing this?

I have 2 dynos and my jvm settigs are

```
-Xms768m -Xmx768m -Xmn192m
```

[image]

Comment: What does your `Procfile` look like? I'm wondering if you are binding to the correct port, which is configured with `$PORT` env var.

Comment: I tried adding --port $PORT to procfile and still did not work

Comment: can you share the full log output?

Comment: Are you binding the port correctly? I had this issue and I got it resolved by forcing Spring Boot to use the Heroku assigned Port.